# Visualize outcome of Linear Mixed-Effects model

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm running a Linear Mixed-Effects `model` on data called `Model_df`. The `model` returns a significant correlation between the response variable `EDA_G_specific_responses` (electrodermal activity responses that cross, or do not cross, the 0.05 μSiemens threshold) and the main fixed effect `G_expressivity`(expressivity of storytellers' gestures during storytellings):

```
model <- lmer(EDA_G_specific_responses ~ G_expressivity + G_Climax + Position + Role + 
                Partcpt + G_Climax:Role + Position:Role + (1 + Position | File/Partcpt) + 
                (1 | Partcpt) + (1 | Story), data = Model_df)
```

How can I **visualize** the model outcome, *specifically the correlation between `EDA_G_specific_responses ~ G_expressivity`*?

```
Model_df <- structure(list(Story = c("Beer", "Beer", "Beer", "Beer", "Beer", 
"Beer", "Beer", "Beer", "Beer", "Beer", "Drawing", "Drawing", 
"Drawing", "Drawing", "Drawing", "Drawing", "Drawing", "Drawing", 
"Drawing", "Drawing", "Drawing", "Drawing", "Drawing", "Drawing", 
"Drawing", "Drawing", "Drawing", "Drawing", "Drawing", "Drawing", 
"Easy", "Easy", "Easy", "Easy", "Easy", "Easy", "Easy", "Easy", 
"Easy", "Easy", "Easy", "Easy", "Easy", "Easy", "Easy", "Easy", 
"Easy", "Easy", "Easy", "Easy", "Guessing", "Guessing", "Guessing", 
"Guessing", "Guessing", "Guessing", "Guessing", "Guessing", "Hiking", 
"Hiking", "Hiking", "Hiking", "Hiking", "Hiking", "Hiking", "Hiking", 
"Hiking", "Hiking", "Hiking", "Hiking", "Hiking", "Hiking", "Hiking", 
"Hiking", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", 
"Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", 
"Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", 
"Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", 
"Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", 
"Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", 
"Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", 
"Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", 
"Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", "Letters", 
"Letters", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", 
"Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", 
"Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", 
"Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", 
"Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", 
"Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", 
"Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", 
"Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", 
"Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", "Missing", 
"Missing", "Missing", "Narrow", "Narrow", "Narrow", "Narrow", 
"Narrow", "Narrow", "Narrow", "Narrow", "Narrow", "Narrow", "Narrow", 
"Narrow", "Narrow", "Narrow", "Narrow", "Narrow", "Narrow", "Narrow", 
"Narrow", "Narrow", "Narrow", "Narrow", "Narrow", "Narrow", "Pocket", 
"Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", 
"Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", 
"Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", 
"Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", 
"Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", 
"Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", 
"Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", 
"Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", 
"Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", 
"Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Pocket", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", 
"Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", 
"Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", 
"Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", 
"Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", 
"Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", 
"Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", "Quiet", 
"Quiet", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", 
"Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", 
"Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", 
"Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", 
"Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", 
"Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Stupid", "Stupid", 
"Stupid", "Stupid", "Stupid", "Stupid", "Stupid", "Stupid", "Stupid", 
"Stupid", "Stupid", "Stupid", "Stupid", "Stupid", "Stupid", "Stupid", 
"Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", 
"Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", 
"Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", 
"Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", 
"Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", 
"Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", 
"Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", 
"Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", 
"Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", 
"Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", 
"Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet", "Toilet"), Partcpt = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), File = c("F06", "F06", "F06", 
"F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F07", "F07", 
"F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", 
"F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", 
"F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", 
"F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", 
"F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", 
"F08", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", 
"F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F07", 
"F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", 
"F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", 
"F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", 
"F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", 
"F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", 
"F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F05", "F05", "F05", 
"F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", 
"F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", 
"F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", 
"F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", 
"F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", 
"F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", 
"F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", "F05", 
"F05", "F05", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", 
"F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", 
"F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", 
"F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", 
"F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", "F06", 
"F06", "F06", "F06", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
"F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
"F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
"F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
"F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
"F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
"F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", 
"F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01"), G_size = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), G_Climax = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1
), G_expressivity = c(0, 0.143, 0.214, 0.214, 0.143, 0, 0.143, 
0.214, 0.214, 0.143, 0.071, 0.071, 0.071, 0, 0.071, 0.071, 0.143, 
0.143, 0.143, 0.071, 0.071, 0.071, 0.071, 0, 0.071, 0.071, 0.143, 
0.143, 0.143, 0.071, 0.214, 0.143, 0.071, 0.143, 0.143, 0.143, 
0.214, 0.143, 0.214, 0.143, 0.071, 0.143, 0.214, 0.143, 0.071, 
0.143, 0.143, 0.143, 0.214, 0.143, 0.143, 0.071, 0.071, 0.643, 
0.143, 0.071, 0.071, 0.643, 0.214, 0.286, 0.143, 0, 0, 0.071, 
0.286, 0.214, 0.214, 0.286, 0.143, 0, 0, 0.071, 0.286, 0.214, 
0.071, 0.143, 0.167, 0.214, 0.143, 0.143, 0.143, 0.143, 0, 0.214, 
0.286, 0.143, 0.286, 0.143, 0.214, 0, 0.214, 0.071, 0.214, 0.143, 
0.214, 0.143, 0.143, 0.143, 0.143, 0.214, 0.071, 0.071, 0.143, 
0.167, 0.214, 0.143, 0.143, 0.143, 0.143, 0, 0.214, 0.286, 0.143, 
0.286, 0.143, 0.214, 0, 0.214, 0.071, 0.214, 0.143, 0.214, 0.143, 
0.143, 0.143, 0.143, 0.214, 0.071, 0.429, 0, 0, 0.143, 0.214, 
0, 0.286, 0.167, 0.143, 0.071, 0.071, 0, 0.143, 0, 0.071, 0.143, 
0.214, 0.071, 0.214, 0.429, 0, 0, 0.143, 0.214, 0, 0.286, 0.167, 
0.143, 0.071, 0.071, 0, 0.143, 0, 0.071, 0.143, 0.214, 0.071, 
0.214, 0.429, 0, 0, 0.143, 0.214, 0.286, 0.167, 0.143, 0.071, 
0.071, 0, 0.143, 0.071, 0.143, 0.214, 0.071, 0.214, 0.286, 0.071, 
0.143, 0.214, 0.071, 0.357, 0.214, 0.143, 0.286, 0.071, 0.143, 
0.214, 0.071, 0.357, 0.214, 0.143, 0.286, 0.071, 0.143, 0.214, 
0.071, 0.357, 0.214, 0.143, 0.071, 0.071, 0.143, 0.143, 0.214, 
0.214, 0, 0.286, 0.214, 0.214, 0.143, 0.214, 0.071, 0, 0, 0.071, 
0.071, 0.143, 0.143, 0.071, 0.214, 0.071, 0.071, 0.143, 0.143, 
0.214, 0.143, 0.143, 0.071, 0.071, 0, 0.071, 0.143, 0.143, 0.071, 
0.071, 0.143, 0.143, 0.214, 0.214, 0, 0.286, 0.214, 0.214, 0.143, 
0.214, 0.071, 0, 0, 0.071, 0.071, 0.143, 0.143, 0.071, 0.214, 
0.071, 0.071, 0.143, 0.143, 0.214, 0.143, 0.143, 0.071, 0.071, 
0, 0.071, 0.143, 0.143, 0.214, 0.071, 0, 0, 0.071, 0, 0.286, 
0.143, 0.143, 0.286, 0.214, 0.071, 0.214, 0.214, 0.143, 0.143, 
0.071, 0.071, 0.214, 0.286, 0.214, 0.143, 0.143, 0.214, 0.071, 
0, 0, 0.071, 0, 0.286, 0.143, 0.143, 0.286, 0.214, 0.071, 0.214, 
0.214, 0.143, 0.143, 0.071, 0.071, 0.214, 0.286, 0.214, 0.143, 
0.143, 0.071, 0.143, 0.143, 0.071, 0.214, 0, 0.071, 0.071, 0.071, 
0.214, 0.214, 0.214, 0.143, 0.143, 0.143, 0, 0.143, 0.071, 0.143, 
0.143, 0.071, 0.214, 0, 0.071, 0.071, 0.071, 0.214, 0.214, 0.214, 
0.143, 0.143, 0.143, 0, 0.143, 0.071, 0.143, 0.143, 0.071, 0.214, 
0, 0.071, 0.071, 0.071, 0.214, 0.214, 0.214, 0.143, 0.143, 0.143, 
0, 0.143, 0.143, 0.071, 0.143, 0.071, 0, 0.071, 0.286, 0, 0.143, 
0.071, 0.143, 0.071, 0, 0.071, 0.286, 0, 0.143, 0, 0.214, 0.071, 
0.071, 0.143, 0, 0.286, 0.143, 0, 0.286, 0.429, 0.286, 0.143, 
0.214, 0.143, 0.571, 0.5, 0.286, 0.214, 0.143, 0.143, 0.143, 
0.286, 0.429, 0.143, 0, 0.214, 0.071, 0.071, 0.143, 0, 0.286, 
0.143, 0, 0.286, 0.429, 0.286, 0.143, 0.214, 0.143, 0.571, 0.5, 
0.286, 0.214, 0.143, 0.143, 0.143, 0.286, 0.429, 0.143, 0, 0.214, 
0.071, 0.071, 0.143, 0, 0.286, 0.143, 0, 0.286, 0.429, 0.286, 
0.143, 0.214, 0.143, 0.571, 0.5, 0.286, 0.214, 0.143, 0.143, 
0.143, 0.286, 0.429), Position = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L), Role = c("st", "st", "st", "st", "st", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "st", "st", "st", "st", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", 
"st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", 
"st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", 
"st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "st", "st", "st", "st", 
"st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", 
"st", "st", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "st", 
"st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", 
"st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", 
"st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", 
"st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "st", "st", "st", "st", 
"st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", 
"st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "st", "st", 
"st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", 
"st", "st", "st", "st", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "st", "st", 
"st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", 
"st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", "st", 
"st", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", 
"rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc"), EDA_G_specific_responses = c(1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
)), row.names = c(NA, -463L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), na.action = structure(c(`43` = 43L, `44` = 44L, `45` = 45L, 
`46` = 46L, `176` = 176L, `184` = 184L, `214` = 214L, `215` = 215L, 
`216` = 216L, `217` = 217L, `218` = 218L, `219` = 219L, `220` = 220L, 
`221` = 221L, `222` = 222L, `223` = 223L, `224` = 224L, `225` = 225L
), class = "omit"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to visualize your model, but you can't really see it "all at once", since it is a complex six-dimensional structure. If you just want to see how the value of `EDA_G_specific_responses` changes in response to `G_expressivity`, the standard way to do this would be to look at estimated *marginal* effect of `G_expressivity`, that is, the plot of the predictions from the model with the other variables held constant at their mean values.

This is very easy with the `ggeffects` package:

```r
library(ggeffects)

ggemmeans(model, terms = "G_expressivity") |> plot()
```

[image]

The `ggemmeans` function will automatically color and facet multiple `terms` up to a maximum of 4, so that you can see more of the fixed effects in your model:

```r
ggemmeans(model, terms = c("G_expressivity", "G_Climax", "Position", "Role")) |> 
  plot()
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

From looking at your data, it appears that your outcome is binary data, so you may need a binomial `glmer` rather than `lmer`:

```r
model <- glmer(EDA_G_specific_responses ~ G_expressivity + G_Climax + Position + 
                 Role + Partcpt + G_Climax:Role + Position:Role + 
                 (1 + Position | File/Partcpt) + (1 | Partcpt) + (1 | Story), 
               family = binomial, data = Model_df)
```

In either case, adding points to your plot is done via adding a ggplot layer:

```r
ggemmeans(model, terms = c("G_expressivity", "G_Climax")) |> 
  plot() +
  geom_point(data = Model_df, shape = "|",
             aes(x = G_expressivity, y = EDA_G_specific_responses,
                 colour = factor(G_Climax)), size = 10,
             inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, fantastic. How can I plot the observed values into the effects plot?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann actually, from looking at your data, isn't your outcome a binary variable (0 and 1 only)? Should this be a binomial rather than linear model?

Comment: Thanks again for spotting the necessity of computing a binomial model and the very nice visauliazation. How would you describe in one sentence (or two) what the plot shows? (`G_Climax` captures whether a gesture occurred before (0) or during (1) the story Climax)