# Can I add a randoma effect to stat_poly_eq() in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I am interested in adding a random effect to a ggplot using stat_poly_eq().

```
library (ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

data (mtcars)
mtcars$gear   <- factor (mtcars$gear)
mtcars$cyl    <- factor (mtcars$cyl)
transmission <- data.frame ( code = c(1, 0),
                             type = c("manual", "automatic"))
mtcars$transmission <- setNames (transmission$type, transmission$code) [as.character (mtcars$am)]

my.formula <- y ~ x 

p <- ggplot       (data = mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg, group = 1)) +
  facet_wrap   (~transmission, strip.position = "top", scales = "fixed", nrow = 1) +
  ggtitle      ("car horsepower (hp) to effiency (mpg) based on cylinder and number of gears for American vs others cars") +
  geom_point   ( size = 6, shape = 16, aes ( shape=cyl, color=cyl) ) +
  scale_color_manual (name       = "number of cylinder",
                      labels     = c (paste (levels(mtcars$cyl), "cylinders")),
                      values     = c("turquoise", "orange", "red")) +
  
  geom_smooth  (data = mtcars, method="lm",
                formula = my.formula,
                se = FALSE,
                color = "blue",
                fill = "blue") +
  
  stat_poly_eq (formula = my.formula,
                aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label), after_stat(adj.rr.label), after_stat(p.value.label), sep = "~~~")),
                parse = TRUE,
                size = 4,
                col = "black") +
  
  theme        (panel.spacing    = unit(0, "lines"),
                strip.background = element_blank(),
                plot.title       = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                                                color = "black",
                                                size  = 14,
                                                face  = "bold.italic"),
                strip.placement = "outside")
print(p)
```

[image: working graph before random effect]

I'd assume blocking and adding random effects would be the same as for any linear model (+ Block OR + (1 | random.effect).  However, I am not getting the code to work.  Does anyone have any good ideas?

Here is an example of what I am talking about using mtcars.  In this case I'll ask you to imagine that the vehicle weight is a random effect (I understand that it is likely not random effect but the example dataset doesn't include a good random effect. Here is the code I use to add the random effect and the regression line fails.

```
my.formula <- y ~ x + (1 | mtcars$wt)
```

Comment: There are a few problems here. You can't specify random effects in `lm`, so your formula wouldn't work using that method. There is no column called `weight` in `mtcars` (vehicle weight is called `wt`). You are passing an entire column as the random effect, whereas `geom_smooth` is splitting the data into 6 groups (one for each color / panel combination). Best to use `predict` from an actual mixed model to get the line you want, and probably best annotate the plot with the text you want to see.

Comment: @AllanCameron thanks for the tips.  (1) I changed the example to mtcars$wt. (2) We need the graph to have color based on factor but the line should represent all the data for each facet. (3) I am able to get this to work with my dataset until I add random effects to the model, then it crashes. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: but you're _not_ adding random effects to the model. The `(1 | data$wt)` syntax doesn't add random effects in `lm`. That syntax _is_ used in some packages to specify random effects (such as `lme4::lmer`) but you can't just use it in `lm`.

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, this is the root of my question.  Can ggplot functions account for random effects?  If so, how?  Also, I am still reading up on predict.

Comment: If you check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76892611/visualize-outcome-of-linear-mixed-effects-model/76893017#76893017) answer of mine about visualising linear mixed effects models, you might get some ideas. If you're struggling to apply it, ping me here and I can try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `method = "lm"` in `geom_smooth`, you are using the function `lm` to create a simple linear model on each subgroup of points in each panel. `ggplot` will split the data frame into multiple smaller data frames to do this. You cannot pass an entire column of the original data to your formula, since it will contain all the rows of the data frame, and hence be a different length from all the other variables in the subgroup being analysed.

Furthermore, ggplot uses the `predict` function to get predicted values for your regression. It uses the range of the x axis to generate the values at which to predict. If you use variables other than `y` and `x` in the formula to `geom_smooth`, it will not know what values you want for these variables in the `predict` function, and will simply not work. You can therefore *only* use `y` and `x` in the formula passed to `geom_smooth`. This means it isn't suitable for mixed effect models, which by definition use more than one variable on the right hand side.

To make matters worse, the `(1 | wt)` syntax does not create a random intercept mixed effects model inside `lm`. If you want to create a mixed-effects model, you need to use a specifically-designed function like `lmer` from the `lme4` package.

For both the above reasons, `stat_poly_eq` will not work in this scenario. It is designed only to work with `lm` regressions.

However, all is not lost. It is still possible to get the plot you want using `ggplot` as long as we work through the necessary steps.

First, let's create a data set that lends itself to a mixed effects model:

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(1:10, 5) + runif(50), 
  y = rep(1:10, 5) + rep(rnorm(5, 5, 5), each = 10) + rnorm(50),
  z = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 10)
)
```

We can load `lme4` and create our model with a random intercept

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix

model <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|z), data = df)

model
#> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#> Formula: y ~ x + (1 | z)
#>    Data: df
#> REML criterion at convergence: 161.1372
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
#>  z        (Intercept) 3.3242  
#>  Residual             0.9568  
#> Number of obs: 50, groups:  z, 5
#> Fixed Effects:
#> (Intercept)            x  
#>      2.8896       0.9926
```

Now, let's say we want to plot the implied regression lines for each group of our data, as well as the overall fixed effect in ggplot. We can start by creating a data frame of `x` and `z` values for which we want to predict the `y` values. We then feed this to `predict` and store the result:

```r
plot_df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, 5), z = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 10))
plot_df$y <- predict(model, newdata = plot_df)
```

From the comments it seems that you also want an R-squared and p values. Just be aware that these are not as straightforward to obtain or interpret for mixed models, and you should ensure you know what these mean when putting them on your plot. You can obtain them in this case as follows:

```r
r2 <- round(performance::r2_nakagawa(model)$R2_conditional, 3)
pval <-  scales::pvalue(car::Anova(model, test = "F")$`Pr(>F)`, add_p = TRUE)
```

All that remains for us to do now is plot our raw data, the regression lines, the overall fixed effect, and the equation for the fixed effect using a custom annotation extracted from our model:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = z)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(data = plot_df, linetype = 2) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = fixef(model)[1], slope = fixef(model)[2],
                  linetype = "Fixed effect"), key_glyph = draw_key_path,
              linewidth = 1) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  labs(linetype = NULL, color = "groups (z)") +
  annotation_custom(grid::textGrob(
    bquote(bold(~y == 
             .(round(fixef(model)[1], 3)) + .(round(fixef(model)[2], 3)) * x) ~
             ~~~italic(paste(.(pval))~~~R^2 == .(r2))),
    x = 0.05, y = 0.9, hjust = 0, gp = grid::gpar(cex = 1.2))) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  ggtitle("Illustration of mixed effects model with random intercept") +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        plot.title = element_text(face = 2, hjust = 0.5),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, linewidth = 0.2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Allan for helping a stranger.  Your example was very informative and it also brought me to lme4 sleepstudy page which further demonstrates this.  I recommend anyone else who is learning this to look at this page as well. 
 https://cdsbasel.github.io/dataanalytics_rsessions/_sessions/CausalInference/intro_lme4.html

Comment: I do have a question.  How do we print the p-value and R2 or adj.R2 along with the Fixed Effect Formula.  I assume that after_stat(adj.rr.label) isn't going to work here.

Comment: @JamesR it _is_ possible (see my update), but I would strongly encourage you to read up on r-squared and p values in mixed models, since their meaning is debatable. See [here](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#how-do-i-compute-a-coefficient-of-determination-r2-or-an-analogue-for-glmms) for an in-depth discussion.