# How to add stat results to a ggplot regressions with random effects and facet_wrap using the fitted function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, random-effects

This is a continuation of my previous question listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77608417/can-i-add-a-randoma-effect-to-stat-poly-eq-in-ggplot) and works off of the lme4 tutorial for sleepstudy [here](https://cdsbasel.github.io/dataanalytics_rsessions/_sessions/CausalInference/intro_lme4.html).

My 1st question is how can I use ggplot to graph a regression with random effects using facit wrap and provide the r2.adj and pval for each individual regression, not the regression of all datapoints.

The second question continues with the first question, but how do I add end of lines using annotation_custom() so that the stats show up in the upper left corner while the y=mx+b, r2.adj, and the pval are each on their own line, allowing the fontsize to be larger.

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(ggpmisc)
library(scales)
library(performance)
library(car)

str(sleepstudy)
data("sleepstudy")

ggplot.model.labels  <- function (model.num, df) {

  datafit = fitted(model.num)
  r2 <- round(performance::r2_nakagawa(model.num)$R2_conditional, 3)
  pval <-  scales::pvalue(car::Anova(model.num, test = "F")$`Pr(>F)`, add_p = TRUE)
  ggplot(df, aes(Days, Reaction, group=Subject, colour=Subject)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line(aes(y=datafit), linetype=1) +
    annotation_custom(grid::textGrob(
      bquote(bold(~y == 
                    .(round(fixef(model.num)[1], 3)) + .(round(fixef(model.num)[2], 3)) * x) ~
               ~~~italic(paste(.(pval))~~~R^2 == .(r2))),
      x = 0.05, y = 0.9, hjust = 0, gp = gpar(col = "black", fontsize = 5))) +
    
    facet_wrap(~Subject, ncol=9) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0, 10),breaks=c(0,10)) +
    theme_minimal()
}

model4 <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + Days + (1 + Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
ggplot.model.labels (model4, sleepstudy)
```

[image: Image 1]

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to me that you aren't quite getting the hang of what a mixed model is. You can certainly get a formula, an R squared and a p value for a simple linear regression in each panel, but a mixed model doesn't _have_ individual p values and r squared for "each individual regression", because a mixed model _doesn't do_ lots of individual regressions. It does a _single_ regression. Are you just looking for simple regression values in each panel?

Comment: Thank you for responding again Allan. Yes, I understand what you are saying, yet I was directed to looking at individual regression via a CrossValidated question I asked some time back. The individual that helped with this question (Dave2e) warned me away from multiple regression. "I do recommend splitting your data and performing the regression on each part, the exercise should make it clearer."(https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/547577/multiple-regression-r-output-how-to-interpret-the-intercept).

Comment: So the approach I am taking in the analysis for this question is, first, to look at model effects in the lm to see if there is significance then, second, using this individual regression analysis to visualize the data (e.g. over years and populations) as POST HOC analysis across my data before making conclusions or asking more questions.

Comment: This does present a second solution to the graphing problem, take the regression results from my stats dataframe and put them into each these figures, as I have all of these calculations made already. However adding this information to each figure form the df hasn't been easy as it sounds for me either.